# Я не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы у меня в поля могли вводить только положительные числа

Tags: html

```js
function draw_ellipse() { //D=document.forms[0].D.value
  var A = document.getElementById('A').value
  var B = document.getElementById('B').value
  sEllipse = '<svg height="500" width="500">' +
    '<ellipse cx="250" cy="250" rx="' + A + '" ry="' + B + '" style="fill:#FF4500;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />' +
    '<line x1="250" y1="0" x2="250" y2="500" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />' +
    '<line x1="0" y1="250" x2="500" y2="250" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />' +
    '</svg>'
  document.getElementById('K').innerHTML = sEllipse
}
```

```html
<h1 align=center>Построение эллипса
  <BR/>
</h1>
<TABLE BORDER=0>
  <THEAD>
    <TR>Задайте длины полуосей</TR>
  </THEAD>
  <TR>
    <TD>Горизонтальная a=</TD>
    <TD>
      <INPUT TYPE="text" name="A" ID="A" />
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>Вертикальная b=</TD>
    <TD>
      <INPUT TYPE="text" name="B" ID="B" />
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD> &nbsp; </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <INPUT type="BUTTON" value='ПОСТРОИТЬ' onclick="draw_ellipse()" />
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<div ID="K" style=" position:absolute;  top: 100px;  left:500px;  height:500px;  width:500px;  background-color:#FFDEAD">
</div>
```

Comment: Слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы находится знак "галочка". Он там для Вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function draw_ellipse() { //D=document.forms[0].D.value
  var A = document.getElementById('A').value
  var B = document.getElementById('B').value
  sEllipse = '<svg height="500" width="500">' +
    '<ellipse cx="250" cy="250" rx="' + A + '" ry="' + B + '" style="fill:#FF4500;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />' +
    '<line x1="250" y1="0" x2="250" y2="500" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />' +
    '<line x1="0" y1="250" x2="500" y2="250" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />' +
    '</svg>'
  document.getElementById('K').innerHTML = sEllipse
}

function handleKeydown(e) {
  if (e.key == '-')
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<h1 align=center>Построение эллипса
  <BR/>
</h1>
<TABLE BORDER=0>
  <THEAD>
    <TR>Задайте длины полуосей</TR>
  </THEAD>
  <TR>
    <TD>Горизонтальная a=</TD>
    <TD>
      <INPUT type="number" name="A" ID="A" onkeydown="handleKeydown(event)" />
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>Вертикальная b=</TD>
    <TD>
      <INPUT type="number" name="B" ID="B" onkeydown="handleKeydown(event)" />
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD> &nbsp; </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <INPUT type="BUTTON" value='ПОСТРОИТЬ' onclick="draw_ellipse()" />
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<div ID="K" style=" position:absolute;  top: 100px;  left:500px;  height:500px;  width:500px;  background-color:#FFDEAD">
</div>
```

Comment: пасибаа большоее